# Is it possible to bevel vertex of a plane using geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bevel

I want to use the geometry nodes to select specific/random vertex on a plane and do a operation like the bevel tool, but I don't know if this is possible with the nodes currently available.

[image]

Comment: i am sure it is - but depending on the geometry it is pretty complex mathematic (at least from my perspective)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To bevel random vertices in a grid, one approach might be to bevel **all** the vertices, by splitting face edges, converting to curve, and filleting.

Then collapse the chosen fraction of vertices back to their original stored position, before converting back to mesh and re-merging:

[image]

Of course, you could change your selection method to choose specified vertices, rows/columns, avoid perimeter, etc.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just for an Idea: I would try to make instances of those small squares rotated 45 deg., then extrude those original squares after splitting the edges, also extrude small squares, then make a bool operation, then delete all extruded by selecting sides and top.
And You of course can make random distribution of those small squares.

[image: my experimental node setup for classic tiles]

[image]