# Bevel mesh edges selected in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, bevel

I'm looking for a way to work around the absence of a bevel node in Geometry Nodes (GN from now on). I've studied the questions/answers in the topic but couldn't figure how the solutions offered work and which would work (or work best) in my case.

My case: I'm using GN to generate side walks along streets. Input is a mesh edited of a simple plane which is the outline of the street network. I use GN to inset and extrude  faces to create the side walks. Now I'd like to bevel the corners of the side walks as marked on my screenshot.

[image: edges to bevel]

My question: what workaround method would be best here?

The below answer suggests it is possible to create a vertex group, add a bevel modifier limited to that vertex group, output a GN selection in the form of a Store Named Attribute.. but I don't understand how the link is created between the content of the Store Named Attribute and the vertex group - doesn't seem to work for me.

[bevel-geometry-nodes-output](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270558/possible-to-bevel-geometry-nodes-group-output)

This other answer suggests it is possible to get some kind of bevel done inside of GN. Would this work in my case if I bevelled the corner vertices before extruding?

[bevel-vertex-of-a-plane](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274738/is-it-possible-to-bevel-vertex-of-a-plane-using-geometry-nodes)

Also I wonder if selecting the corners before extruding, add vertices both directions near the corners, turn those edges to curve, fillet curve, back to mesh and somehow integrate back into the mesh would work? I'm not sure about the integrate back part..

Here's the node setup:

[image: NodeSetup]

Comment: Hehe I can't way for a bevel node to be available in GN to avoid having to jump through hoops like that. Note sure about the ETA though :) https://devtalk.blender.org/t/bevel-v2-geometry-nodes/27829/5

Comment: Possibly relevant, but with selection, rather than random control: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/274755/35559

Comment: @Robin Betts I thought the same, possibly relevant, that's why I also refer to it in my question. I gave it a quick try but couldn't make it work in my file - honestly I don't understand how it works.

Comment: Ooops .. didn't get your ref. right :) I'll see if I can adapt it, when I get  some time.. but it would help to know how you made your chunk of road in the first place, whether you expect it to be a component of  something bigger, etc.etc. So a share of the relevant bit on https://blend-exchange.com/ would help.

Comment: @Robin Betts I added a screenshot of my node setup. It's the very beginning of a street generator, nothing complicated at this stage. I guess I shouldn't share the file because of the BB Inset node..

Comment: To assign values to a vertex group so you can then discrimnate by it in a bevel modifier, you can use this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/275405/60486 And to assign a value to a bevel weight, you could use something similar to this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/247840/60486

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady thanks uh, I don't think I'm ready for something as complicated as that.. I'm hoping to find a way inside GN, like turn to curve, fillet, turn to mesh, join together. I'll try again going in that direction.

Comment: @Booth I only suggested it (using bevel modifier) because you specifically mentioned it as a researched possibility in your question.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady thank you, yes I did, I'm open to solutions. I mentioned the bevel modifier solution ranking high because I thought I'm only missing a small trick and it would be a relatively simple one.